# Возможность принять описание метки без возможности редактирования

Tags: дефект, поддержка, метки

В очереди проверок прилетела [предлагаемая правка](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/108983) (создание) краткого описания метки:

[image: нельзя улучшить]

Судя по тексту я могу улучшить правку, а судя по кнопкам - нет. Вообще кажется довольно странным, когда уже можно принимать правки меток, но при этом нельзя вносить в них улучшения, которые потом мог бы утвердить кто-то другой.

Т.о. для реального улучшения правки надо:

1. либо:

   - принять правку
   - отклонить правку, скопировав всё полезное, что есть в предложенной правке (плагиат)
2. дождаться пока эта правка вступит в силу или будет отвергнута
3. предложить свою правку

Пока ждешь п.2 можно вообще забыть о том, что хотел отредактировать. В идеале описание можно было бы улучшить сразу по месту.

Данный механизм, как мне кажется, нуждается в доработке. Как минимум нужно привести сообщение о возможных действиях в соответствие с действительностью.

Comment: Это баг чисто ruSO или глобальный?

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov в текстовом описании есть "improve". Есть ли там кнопка - не знаю. Скорее всего, нет.

Comment: Меня просто больше парит отсутствие самой возможности, а не тескты.